# error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found. error: failed linking references

Tags: android, flutter, dart, build, android-gradle-plugin

When I upgrade the flutter sdk to v1.12.13+hotfix-stable, I am easily creating a debug file but as soon as I am trying to create a release file I am getting a build failed exception.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sms:verifyReleaseResources'.

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
  \build\sms\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:236: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not
found.
  \build\sms\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:237: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
  error: failed linking references.
```

Comment: run flutter doctor or check your gradle version .

Comment: check your gradle version

Comment: There is no issue found in flutter doctor and I also checked gradle version which is
com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1 
compileSdkVersion is 28

Comment: update all plugins  and gradle change with 3.4.2

Comment: I have update gradle with 3.4.2, but it is not working for me.

Comment: are you using some extra plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using **pin_view: ^1.0.1** plugin, in which the **sms** plugin is use internally, which was creating this problem. Now I am using **pin_code_text_field: ^1.5.1**
plugin for same. This new plugin remove my problem.